# Firebase Realtime Database for web app giving SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 (function(){
     const preObj=document.getElementById('object');




     const preObjRef = firebase.database().ref().child('object');

     preObjRef.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val())); 

 }());
```

I followed exactly some learning videos, but still receive this error...

the error in this line of code:
 `preObjRef.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));`

error text:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Post a bit more of your code please!
The code you posted actually has one `)` too much...

Comment: you can see the attached image..

Comment: Try this: `snap => { console.log(snap.val()) } )`
1. Don't show us your firebase config.
2. Don't EVER post code as picture - always post it in the question (copy&paste?!)

Comment: for security ,I know ,but I just try for just learing and i have no previouse experience in asking here..

Comment: I just tried your solution but no thing happened!

Comment: That's why I say it. ;) We all started at a certain point. Can't help sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're running this code in an environment that doesn't understand the ES6 fat-arrow syntax. In that case you can replace it with:

```
preObjRef.on('value', function(snap) { console.log(snap.val()); });
```

I'd also consider upgrading the environment where you run the code, because more and more systems assume ES6 support.

Comment: thank you so much ..finaly,it works..thank you again..so,can you suggest some names for good environments to work on ?